# Как пользоватся файлами txt в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Вот моя ситуация: у меня есть игра, игровое поле которой представляет прямоугольник n*m, и мне очень удобно информацию о каждой клетке поля сохранять в файле txt (точнее 1 файл на 1 уровень). Пишу я на Unity, в папку Assets я закинул папку с уровнями. В редакторе всё работает хорошо. Неприятный тот момент, что когда я компилирую игру и запускаю её просто (как .exe файл), уровни програма не находит. Вопрос состоит в том, как исправить эту проблему, или, если такового решения нет, посоветуйте альтернативные решения. Зарание спасибо!

Comment: Код чтения из файла покажите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что вы положили свой текстовый файл не в папку Resources.

Все ресурсы вашей игры, которые вы хотите загружать динамически должны находиться в папке Resources, иначе загрузка будет работать только в редакторе Unity.

При этом стоит заметить, что в вашем проекте может быть несколько папок с именем Resources (в различных директориях проекта). Это разрешается тем, что при компиляции проекта Unity собирает все содержимое всех папок Resources в одну "виртуальную" папку.

Загружая сам ресурс вы должны искать его начиная с папки Resources, например: если ваш файл Level.txt находится по следующему пути в проекте - `Assets/GameData/Resources/Levels/Level.txt`, то загружать его в игре стоит по пути `Levels/Level.txt` методом `Resources.Load()` подробнее [в документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html), подробнее о директории Resources [здесь](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/resources-folder)

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли, я просто хранил txt в папке Assets, поэтому такая проблема и возникла.